# How to align/stick two widgets if other row or column widget has different (mostly bigger) size with that column or row?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Button(root,text="a", width = 30, height = 30).grid(row=1,column=1)
Button(root,text="b").grid(row=2,column=1)
Button(root,text="c").grid(row=3,column=1)
Button(root,text="d").grid(row=1,column=4,sticky="n")
Button(root,text="e").grid(row=2,column=4,sticky="n",pady=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to let `d` widget stick with `e` widget on the top of the frame, how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `d` and `e` in a frame as below:

```py
f = Frame(root)
f.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='n')
Button(f, text="d").pack()
Button(f, text="e").pack()
```

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking the *tick* under the vote buttons.